# how can i implement a map (not Google maps) in Flutter?

Tags: dictionary, flutter, dart

I want to implement a map in flutter (can't use google maps) how can I do it? it's just a normal map with the ability to show current location constantly.

Comment: location on a map?? Then you must use some map if not gmap. May be open street map? Tell your choice then only solution can be explained

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take a look on this package - https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_map

As a map tiles, you can use one of these https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tile_servers (but read open street maps terms of use https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright).

If you want to display current location, you can use this package https://pub.dev/packages/location and you can simply add new marker on the map.

Hope this help!